# Como ordenar Record no Delphi (semelhando ao ORDER BY)?

Tags: array, delphi, classificação, delphi-xe5, mormot

Eu trago alguns registros do banco com uma ordenação específica e jogo pra dentro de um vetor do tipo [`record`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Records_.28traditional.29). Depois preciso adicionar mais itens nesse vetor mantendo a ordenação inicial. Como a ordenação é feita no `SQL` os registros que são adicionados depois acabam indo para o final do vetor.

Quero saber se existe alguma forma de reordenar esse vetor da mesma forma como é feita no `ORDER BY` do `SQL` tendo a opção de ordenar por vários campos. Eu uso [`mORMot`](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html) também mas não encontrei algo na documentação que faça isso.

Eu consegui encontrar um exemplo que faz a ordenação, ele funciona perfeitamente, porém só faz por um campo. Segue o código:

Exemplo de Record:

```
TRegistro = record
   CODIGO: Integer;
   NOME: string;
   DATA: TDateTime;
   CIDADE: string;
end;
TRegistros = array of TRegistro;
```

Ordenação:

```
procedure SortArray(var Matriz: TRegistros);
var
   Posicao1, Posicao2: Integer;
   Temporario: TRegistro; // Variável Temporária para Alternar Valores
begin
   for Posicao1 := 0 to Length(Matriz) - 1 do
   begin
      for Posicao2 := 0 to (Length(Matriz) - 2) do
      begin
         if (Matriz[Posicao2].CODIGO > Matriz[Posicao2 + 1].CODIGO ) then // Ordem Crescente
         begin
            Temporario := Matriz[Posicao2];
            Matriz[Posicao2] := Matriz[Posicao2 + 1];
            Matriz[Posicao2 + 1] := Temporario;
         end;
      end;
   end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando o `Sort` do [`TDynArray`](https://synopse.info/files/html/api-1.18/SynCommons.html#TDYNARRAY) do `mORMot`.
O `Sort` recebe uma função como parâmetro e nele passo a função que faz a comparação dos registros para ordenação. Fiz uma função de comparação e o Arnaud Bouchez deu uma reformulada nela:

```
function OrderBy(const A, B): Integer;
var
   ra: TRegistro absolute A;
   rb: TRegistro absolute B;
begin
   result := ra.COD_USUARIO - rb.COD_USUARIO;
   if result <> 0 then
      exit;
   result := ra.COD_PRIORIDADE - rb.COD_PRIORIDADE;
   if result <> 0 then
      exit;
   if ra.DATA < rb.DATA then
      result := -1
   else if ra.DATA > rb.DATA then
      result := 1;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu quando vou fazer ordenação, tenho preferência em fazer com WHILE, isso por que temos total controle sobre o iterador. No caso do FOR não podemos altera-lo.

```
var
  i: Integer;
  Temporario: TRegistro;
begin
  i := 0;
  while (i < High(Matriz)) do
    begin
      if (Matriz[i].CODIGO > Matriz[i + 1].CODIGO) then
        begin
          Temporario := Matriz[i + 1];
          Matriz[i + 1] := Matriz[i];
          Matriz[i] := Temporario;
          i := 0;
        end
      else
        Inc(i, 1);
    end;
end;
```

Não consegui testar, mas creio que isso pode te ajudar.

Comment: Então, só que essa só faz a ordenação por um campo. Eu precisava de algo semelhante ao `ORDER BY` do `SQL`, ordenar por vários campos.